# Reference Request: Matrix Perturbation Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

As the title says, I am looking for references on the theory of matrix perturbations. I am aware of the text "Matrix Perturbation Theory" by G. W. Stewart and Ji-guang Sun, and would be interested in reading any of your reviews. Other recommendations are also welcome!

Comment: A classical book is : T. Kato, Perturbation theory for linear operators: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kato1.pdf

Comment: Here's a link to Rajendra Bhatia's review of Stewart and Sun's book: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959290451F